# GenesisConfig { | missing `template_module`

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-parachain-template

I Need to create a pallet in substrate and I changed genesis build in substrate in my pallet.

When I run this command it show me this error:

> GenesisConfig { ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ missing template_module

**I don't know what the problem is, please guide me to solve this problem .**

This code is the genesis build in my pallet:

```
#[pallet::genesis_config]
pub struct GenesisConfig<T: Config> {
    default_price: BalanceOf<T>,
}

#[cfg(feature = "std")]
impl<T: Config> Default for GenesisConfig<T> {
    fn default() -> GenesisConfig<T> {
        GenesisConfig { default_price: T::DefaultMembershipPrice::get().saturated_into() }
    }
}

#[pallet::genesis_build]
impl<T: Config> GenesisBuild<T> for GenesisConfig<T> {
    fn build(&self) {
        let n = T::DefaultNumMembership::get();
        for i in 0u64..n {
            let val = DaoMembership {
                dna: None,
                owner: None,
                price: Some(self.default_price.clone()),
                name: None,
            };
            <MembershipsPooled<T>>::insert(i, val);
            log::info!("[info!!] generated membership and pooled: [{:?}]", i);
        }
        <CountForPooled<T>>::put(n);
        <CountForOwned<T>>::put(0);
    }
}
```

and this is configuration in `chain_spec`:

```
use node_template_runtime::{
    AccountId, AuraConfig, BalancesConfig, GenesisConfig, GrandpaConfig, Signature, SudoConfig,
    SystemConfig, WASM_BINARY,
};
use sc_service::ChainType;
use sp_consensus_aura::sr25519::AuthorityId as AuraId;
use sp_core::{sr25519, Pair, Public};
use sp_finality_grandpa::AuthorityId as GrandpaId;
use sp_runtime::traits::{IdentifyAccount, Verify};

// The URL for the telemetry server.
// const STAGING_TELEMETRY_URL: &str = "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/";

/// Specialized `ChainSpec`. This is a specialization of the general Substrate ChainSpec type.
pub type ChainSpec = sc_service::GenericChainSpec<GenesisConfig>;

/// Generate a crypto pair from seed.
pub fn get_from_seed<TPublic: Public>(seed: &str) -> <TPublic::Pair as Pair>::Public {
    TPublic::Pair::from_string(&format!("//{}", seed), None)
        .expect("static values are valid; qed")
        .public()
}

type AccountPublic = <Signature as Verify>::Signer;

/// Generate an account ID from seed.
pub fn get_account_id_from_seed<TPublic: Public>(seed: &str) -> AccountId
where
    AccountPublic: From<<TPublic::Pair as Pair>::Public>,
{
    AccountPublic::from(get_from_seed::<TPublic>(seed)).into_account()
}

/// Generate an Aura authority key.
pub fn authority_keys_from_seed(s: &str) -> (AuraId, GrandpaId) {
    (get_from_seed::<AuraId>(s), get_from_seed::<GrandpaId>(s))
}

pub fn development_config() -> Result<ChainSpec, String> {
    let wasm_binary = WASM_BINARY.ok_or_else(|| "Development wasm not available".to_string())?;

    Ok(ChainSpec::from_genesis(
        // Name
        "Development",
        // ID
        "dev",
        ChainType::Development,
        move || {
            testnet_genesis(
                wasm_binary,
                // Initial PoA authorities
                vec![authority_keys_from_seed("Alice")],
                // Sudo account
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
                // Pre-funded accounts
                vec![
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob//stash"),
                ],
                true,
            )
        },
        // Bootnodes
        vec![],
        // Telemetry
        None,
        // Protocol ID
        None,
        None,
        // Properties
        None,
        // Extensions
        None,
    ))
}

pub fn local_testnet_config() -> Result<ChainSpec, String> {
    let wasm_binary = WASM_BINARY.ok_or_else(|| "Development wasm not available".to_string())?;

    Ok(ChainSpec::from_genesis(
        // Name
        "Local Testnet",
        // ID
        "local_testnet",
        ChainType::Local,
        move || {
            testnet_genesis(
                wasm_binary,
                // Initial PoA authorities
                vec![authority_keys_from_seed("Alice"), authority_keys_from_seed("Bob")],
                // Sudo account
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
                // Pre-funded accounts
                vec![
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Charlie"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Dave"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Eve"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Ferdie"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Charlie//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Dave//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Eve//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Ferdie//stash"),
                ],
                true,
            )
        },
        // Bootnodes
        vec![],
        // Telemetry
        None,
        // Protocol ID
        None,
        // Properties
        None,
        None,
        // Extensions
        None,
    ))
}

/// Configure initial storage state for FRAME modules.
fn testnet_genesis(
    wasm_binary: &[u8],
    initial_authorities: Vec<(AuraId, GrandpaId)>,
    root_key: AccountId,
    endowed_accounts: Vec<AccountId>,
    _enable_println: bool,
) -> GenesisConfig {
    GenesisConfig {
        system: SystemConfig {
            // Add Wasm runtime to storage.
            code: wasm_binary.to_vec(),
        },
        balances: BalancesConfig {
            // Configure endowed accounts with initial balance of 1 << 60.
            balances: endowed_accounts.iter().cloned().map(|k| (k, 1 << 60)).collect(),
        },
        aura: AuraConfig {
            authorities: initial_authorities.iter().map(|x| (x.0.clone())).collect(),
        },
        grandpa: GrandpaConfig {
            authorities: initial_authorities.iter().map(|x| (x.1.clone(), 1)).collect(),
        },
        sudo: SudoConfig {
            // Assign network admin rights.
            key: Some(root_key),
        },
        transaction_payment: Default::default(),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your genesis config in chain_spec.rs

Let add this under  `transaction_payment: Default::default()`
We have 2 ways:

1. `template_module: Default::default()` : Why you can use it. Because you are already implement trait `Default` for `GenesisConfig` in your pallet
   (

```
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
impl<T: Config> Default for GenesisConfig<T> {
    fn default() -> GenesisConfig<T> {
        GenesisConfig { default_price: T::DefaultMembershipPrice::get().saturated_into() }
    }
}
```

2. Import your `TemplateModuleConfig` in this `use node_template_runtime::{ AccountId, AuraConfig, BalancesConfig, GenesisConfig, GrandpaConfig, Signature, SudoConfig, SystemConfig, WASM_BINARY, };`

Then,

```
template_module: TemplateModuleConfig {
        default_price: 100u32.into()
}
```